# Is there a better way to solve this? (Array with designated initializers)?

Tags: c

I'm doing some of those Advent Of Code puzzles just for fun, and it seemed like this problem must have a simpler solution than the one I wrote. My program works, but part of the fun is to try to find the simplest, fastest, most elegant way to write it.

The problem states:

> Lowercase item types a through z have priorities 1 through 26.
> Uppercase item types A through Z have priorities 27 through 52.

(Original puzzle is [here](https://adventofcode.com/2022/day/3) in case you want to see all of it.)

It seems like there should be a very simple way to do this, but it doesn't work so nicely just with ASCII, so I put my own table into memory for fast lookup.

```
static uint8_t map[] = {
        ['a'] = 1,  ['b'] = 2,  ['c'] = 3,  ['d'] = 4,
        ['e'] = 5,  ['f'] = 6,  ['g'] = 7,  ['h'] = 8,
        ['i'] = 9,  ['j'] = 10, ['k'] = 11, ['l'] = 12,
        ['m'] = 13, ['n'] = 14, ['o'] = 15, ['p'] = 16,
        ['q'] = 17, ['r'] = 18, ['s'] = 19, ['t'] = 20,
        ['u'] = 21, ['v'] = 22, ['w'] = 23, ['x'] = 24,
        ['y'] = 25, ['z'] = 26, ['A'] = 27, ['B'] = 28,
        ['C'] = 29, ['D'] = 30, ['E'] = 31, ['F'] = 32,
        ['G'] = 33, ['H'] = 34, ['I'] = 35, ['J'] = 36,
        ['K'] = 37, ['L'] = 38, ['M'] = 39, ['N'] = 40,
        ['O'] = 41, ['P'] = 42, ['Q'] = 43, ['R'] = 44,
        ['S'] = 45, ['T'] = 46, ['U'] = 47, ['V'] = 48,
        ['W'] = 49, ['X'] = 50, ['Y'] = 51, ['Z'] = 52
};
```

My first version was written something like:

```
#define UPRMAGIC 0x26
#define LWRMAGIC 0x60

...

return islower(c) ? c - LWRMAGIC : c - UPRMAGIC;
```

Now, it still seems to me that there must be a nicer way to do this in pure C, but I haven't learned all of the tricks yet. I know there are ways to do it using less memory and less code, or using much more complex data structures, but I liked using a big array because it's a simple and fast data structure. It just seems like there must be a cleaner way of doing it.

Comment: Just make the array `const` and it will be computed at compile-time. That's as fast as it gets.

Comment: So what's the concern here, performance or that the table is a bit verbose?

Comment: It's that it seems like there should be a less verbose way of writing it.

Comment: I can't really think of one unless you are prepared to sacrifice look-up time. C doesn't have "ranges" for designated initializers unless you resort to non-standard GNU extensions.

Comment: Remember, C strings are arrays, so you can always use a string for lookups. `" abc....ABC"` with a space at the front to kick the initial index to `1` means you can use `strchr()`. With a wrapper function you can convert the pointer to an index.

Comment: @tadman But such code will be significantly slower. As would `memchr` even though it is faster than  `strchr`.

Comment: @Lundin That's just a first optimization. This is a case where bitmasking to determine case and `x - 'a'` type approaches work better.

Comment: @tadman Either way you won't be able to beat a branch-free table look-up.

Comment: (Bad alternatives I can think of: a long string literal with 128 escape sequences like `"\x00\x00" ....\x01\x02 ...`. Far less readable. Or some skunky X macro, far less readable.)

Comment: I do wonder why you're focusing on _this_ part of the problem as your optimization. It's one of the least-hit code paths in a practical solution. The main problem to solve is finding duplicates, which can be done in linear time. Then, you only need to compute and sum the priority which can be done adhoc in constant time as each new duplicate is detected. Resetting the data for duplicate detection after processing a rucksack needs constant time. The only reason I see for having this lookup table is if it doubles as a bit-shift for duplicate detection, or if using exotic character encoding.

Comment: If find the `map` table *very* elegant, as it explicitly matches the priority to each character without any tricks or assumptions on what the underlying character codes might be. Well done!

Answer (score 2):

> it doesn't work so nicely just with ASCII

It works relatively well if you can in fact assume ASCII.  Maybe with something like this:

```
static int get_priority(char c) {
    return (c >= 'a') ? (c - 'a' + 1) : (c - 'A' + 27);
}
```

That uses no standard library functions, it might rival your lookup table for speed, and it would certainly yield smaller code size.  You can write it as a macro if you prefer, or even just write the code directly if you don't need to repeat it.

If there's an issue with that, it's because of the possibility that your system's execution character set is not ASCII-compatible.  And that same issue affects your variant with `islower()`, for both assume that the lower- and upper-case Latin letters are assigned groups of contiguous codes, in alphabetical order.  There are character sets in actual use where that is not the case.  The various flavors of [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) are the ones you're most likely to meet.

Your lookup table, on the other hand, is robust against character set issues, and it is fast.  It might use a bit more memory, but we're talking about a few bytes here.

Comment: You will get different values here for non-alpha input characters; that said, the table is incomplete, so some inputs will be UB in the question code.

Comment: Agreed on both counts, @TobySpeight.  But it is implicit in the question (and clearer at its external link) that only the upper- and lowercase Latin letters need to be accommodated.

Answer (score 1):

Using a lookup table seems a very efficient solution. Note however that you should make the table `static const` to ensure it is constructed and initialized at compile time and you should specify its length as `UCHAR_MAX + 1` to ensure any byte appropriately cast as `(uint8_t)` or `(unsigned char)` can be used as in index.  This array would not be considered large today (256 bytes).

Assuming ASCII, you could define this `map` with less code this way:

```
static const uint8_t map[UCHAR_MAX + 1] = {
    ['a'] =  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
            14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26,
    ['A'] = 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39,
            40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52,
};
```

Whether this is *nicer* is a matter of taste.  It is less portable but easier to type and proof read.

Comment: It might be worth adding that this works because of C17 6.7.9 §17. _"...a designation causes the following initializer to begin initialization of the subobject described by the designator. Initialization then continues forward in order, beginning with the next subobject after that described by the designator."_ If one isn't aware of that little trick, then this code ought to be quite hard to read.

Comment: @Lundin: yes, I shall amend the answer. The semantics are consistent with those of `enum` when the values are elided.

Answer (score 0):

Your first version:

> ```
> #define UPRMAGIC 0x26
> #define LWRMAGIC 0x60
>
> ...
>
> return islower(c) ? c - LWRMAGIC : c - UPRMAGIC;
> ```

This is non-portable (works only for ASCII-like execution character sets) and produces unexpected results for non-alpha characters.

The version with the lookup table still needs to validate the input, unless you change the declaration to be `static uint8_t map[UCHAR_MAX+1]`.

I think a likely better bet would be to get the compiler to make the table, like this:

```
uint_fast8_t priority(char c)
{
     switch (c) {
         case 'a': return 1;
         case 'b': return 2;
         ⋮
         case 'Z': return 52;
     }
     assert(false);
     return 0; /* or perhaps 0xff, or 52, as appropriate */
}
```

This isn't shorter code, but is clear and easy for a compiler to optimise.

---

If shorter code is the main objective, it might be best to initialise a table at the beginning of execution (in C++, we would be able to write a `constexpr` initialiser, but this is C):

```
void create_lookup_table(uint8_t table[UCHAR_MAX+1])
{
    static char const priority_names = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                                       "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    for (int i = 0;  i+1 < sizeof priority_names; ++i) {
         table[priority_names[i]] = i+1;
    }
}

static uint8_t map[UCHAR_MAX+1] = { 0 };

int main(void)
{
   create_lookup_table(map);
   /* rest of program here */
}
```